# What is this `Pr` or "Interest" property of an RSS item?

Tags: rss, newsreader

I'm using [the NewsFox RSS](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/newsfox/) reader on Firefox, and it started showing me a column I can't decipher.

What is this `Pr` property of an RSS item? It seems to be called "Interest" in the column menu:

[image: Mystery field]

[The NewsFox home page](http://newsfox.mozdev.org/index.html) is no help; and its documentation is kaput.

"Interest" doesn't seem to be part of [the RSS spec](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification#hrelementsOfLtitemgt). Yet, NewsFox shows this for every feed.

So, what is `Pr` in this context?